# Is the protocol name in URLs case sensitive?

Tags: url, case-sensitive

Is `hTTp://foo.com` the same as `Http://foo.COM`?

I know that hostnames are not sensitive but path names and query parts are sensitive.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The scheme is case-insensitive: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1

The hostname is also case-insensitive, since it's DNS.

The rest is case sensitive.

Answer (score 12):

It is not sensitive in practice but in theory only lower case is allowed.

From [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

> 2.1. The main parts of URLs
>
> A full BNF description of the URL
>   syntax is given in Section 5.
>
> In general, URLs are written as
>   follows:
>
> ```
>    <scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>
> ```
>
> A URL contains the name of the
>   scheme being used () followed 
>   by a colon and then a string (the
>   ) whose
>   interpretation depends on the scheme.
>
> Scheme names consist of a sequence
>   of characters. The lower case
>   letters "a"--"z", digits, and the
>   characters plus ("+"), period
>   ("."), and hyphen ("-") are allowed.
>   For resiliency, programs
>   interpreting URLs should treat upper
>   case letters as equivalent to    lower
>   case in scheme names (e.g., allow
>   "HTTP" as well as "http").

Comment: rfc 3986 updates it, though. Check the metadata at the top: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Answer (score 5):

Citing [RFC3986](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#scheme):

> Although schemes are case-insensitive, the canonical form is lowercase and documents that specify schemes must do so with lowercase letters [...]

Comment: To phrase it differently and as a general guide, most of these RFCs (internet standards related) are strict on producer end and lenient on consumer end.

Answer (score 3):

Well [this document](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html) (for some HTML specification) says:

> URLs in general are case-sensitive (with the exception of machine names). There may be URLs, or parts of URLs, where case doesn't matter, but identifying these may not be easy. Users should always consider that URLs are case-sensitive

And [RFC1738 (Uniform Resource Locators (URL))](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) says (note, a URL has the form `<scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>`):

> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters. The lower case letters "a"--"z", digits, and the characters plus ("+"), period ("."), and hyphen ("-") are allowed. For resiliency, programs interpreting URLs should treat upper case letters as equivalent to lower case in scheme names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as well as "http").

So only lowercase characters are allowed, but uppercase characters are tolerated.
Btw Safari automatically converts to lowercase characters.