# Are URL Schemes on iOS case-sensitive?

Tags: ios, case-sensitive, url-scheme

The official Apple documentation doesn't seem to specify whether iOS URL schemes are case-sensitive or not.

Can I register `myApp` and still get opened for someone calling `openURL:` on `MyApp://params`?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148603/is-the-protocol-name-in-urls-case-sensitive

Comment: @rmaddy - that's how software comes to rely on undefined behaviour and break when you update stuff

Comment: @Bwmat Not really. The standard is that schemes are case-insensitive. But if iOS treated them as case-sensitive (not saying it does), it doesn't matter how it's documented. So trying is just as important. And since the question asks "can" and not "should", then the answer is as simple as trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not case-sensitive.

You can verify this by entering both `sms://` and `sMs://` into the URL box in Safari.

Also, it seems that third-party URL schemes in the Safari address bar now lead to a page not found error. This must be new in iOS 9.3.x, because it did not do this before. Entering the URL into another app (e.g. Notes) and then opening it still works.

**Edit:** the above hypothesis about iOS 9.3.x is actually a bit more nuanced...

They work if…

- You are starting from a ​*blank*​ screen
- A page is still loading when you request the custom URL scheme

They do NOT work if…

- You are on a webpage that has fully loaded before you request the custom URL scheme

Go figure