# Is the `file://` uri prefix something I can hardcode?

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if I can hardcore the `file://` prefix into one of my functions in android.

The function is supposed to determine whether or not the given link points to an external resource on the web, or an internal resource inside the phone itself

```
public Uri generate_image_uri(String link)
{
    // link can be "1DCHiI2.jpg"
    // link can be "file://smiley_face.jpg"

    if (!link.startsWith("file://")
       return Uri.parse("https://i.imgur.com/" + link);
    else
       return Uri.parse(link);
}
```

Is this advisable? Or is there a more "fault tolerant" way of getting `file://`? maybe some function like `getProperFilePrefixForThisAndroidVersion();`?

---

#### In order to clarify my question:

given the following code

`(new File(getFilesDir(), "hello_world.jpg")).toString();`

Is it safe to assume within reasonable probability that the resulting string will always start with `file://` in all current and future Android versions?

Comment: This code `Uri.parse("https://i.imgur.com/" + link)` will generate something like `https://i.imgur.com/file://smiley_face.jpg` are you sure with that?

Comment: @Enzokie It was a simple typo

Comment: What are your strings coming from?

Comment: @SLaks `1DCHiI2.jpg` comes from my own JSON REST endpoint, `file://smiley_face.jpg` comes from `new File(...).toString();`

Comment: **It depends** on what values are allowed for "link". ie: What dictates that it is even relative to imgur? Are `"http://whatever/.."` links accepted? And if so, what should the result be? Depending on such answers the rules might depend merely on 'absolute' and 'relative' URIs.. although I'd likely keep a whitelist approach.

Comment: @user2864740 there is literally only going to be 2 versions. One is something that points to imgur, and something that is internal. The imgur links are provided by a REST endpoint, and the internal links are generated via `new File(...).toString();` so the question is more or less if `new File(...).toString();` always produces a string starting with `file://`, and if so, will `file://` ever change and is it safe to hardcode - or is there a function that I should call instead.

Comment: **Is the `file://` uri prefix something I can hardcode?** I personally say **you can** since I have seen the Volley implementation hardcoded the `http` and `https` checking.

Comment: @Enzokie well, `http` and `https` are universal and well defined in guide lines. I am not sure about `file://` that seems more like an implementation detail (of which I am currently concerned about)

Comment: @AlanSTACK `file://` is a [well-defined URI schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). However, access to such resources is not always allowed depending on security context.. for Android that means Application Permissions.

Comment: @user2864740 So I'm guessing it is safe to assume Android dev's would never change this then?

Comment: @AlanSTACK Well - that's a bit tricky to answer. Because while "file://" is *the* "local file" URI schema, it's not required to open a local file with all API. It depends on context - mainly, does the API expect a *URI* or a filename? (Will it work with either or does it require transformation to a different - equivalent - form?)

Comment: You might also consider handling the [content://](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html) URI.

Comment: Refer also to [Android 7.0 includes changes to permissions that may affect your app](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#permfilesys).

Comment: @user2864740 I have updated my question to clarify what I am asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given:
>
> ```
> (new File(getFilesDir(), "hello_world.jpg")).toString();
> ```
>
> is it safe to assume within reasonable probability that the resulting string will always start with file:// in all current and future Android versions?

No.

According to the javadoc for `File` on Android, File.toString returns:

> *"...  the pathname string of this abstract pathname. This is just the string returned by the getPath() method."*

Not a "file://" URL.

If you want to get a properly formed "file://" URL, do this:

```
 new File(...).toURI().toString()
```

Now, *technically* the protocol for a URL (i.e. "file") is case insensitive:

- [Is the protocol name in URLs case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148603/is-the-protocol-name-in-urls-case-sensitive)

Which means that "FILE://" or "File://" etc are technically valid alternatives.

However, the probability that above expression would *ever* emit anything other than the lower-case form of the protocol is (um) vanishingly small<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - It would entail monumentally stupid decision making by a number of people.  And they are NOT stupid people.</sup>

Comment: But I CAN assume the `file://` prefix, yes?

Comment: @AlanSTACK - It depends how you >> **really** << create the URL string.  Clearly, what you have shown us is imaginary code ... since it patently won't work.  And, as I said, "FILE://" is a technically correct alternative to the form that you are assuming.  Not to mention other technically incorrect alternatives that `URI.parse(...)` etcetera might accept.

Comment: Its literally just this `(new File(getFilesDir(), "hello_world.jpg")).toString();` except replace `hello_world.jpg` with 3 prebundled default pictures. `default_male.jpg`, `default_female.jpg`, `default_genderless.jpg`

Comment: Well, I don't see how that can produce a "file://" URL.  See the javadocs.  And since the behavior *seems* to contradict the javadocs .... all bets are off.

Comment: God damn it, I mistyped again. `(new File(getFilesDir(), "hello_world.jpg")).toURI().toString();`

Comment: OK.  So the last part of my Answer answers that.  (The last sentence to be precise.)